# Protect audio files in HTML5 audio tags

Tags: php, html, audio, mp3, ogg

I am making a site which will have music playing on the site using HTML5  tags and was wondering if there was any way to protect the files from being downloaded?

I am calling the music file through PHP and if needed it selects an OGG file for browsers that don't support MP3.

The actual files are inaccessible to the public but the PHP file can be downloaded and played.

I was wondering if there was anything I could do which would stop people downloading the file but allow it to be played through the  tags?

EDIT:

I know that the user must be able to access the URL for the file to play.

I am wondering how to prevent download when the user accesses the file without the  tag.

I believe YouTube do a similar thing with the HTML5 video tag (either that or all YouTube videos are now free to download)

EDIT 2:

I have noticed that when a file is downloaded by the user, it does not get passed a HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL variable in the $_SERVER array.

Would this be able to prevent people downloading the file by returning a blank file if they directly download it?

Comment: I think I may have stumbled upon a solution using JavaScript to call the file, posting data to the file which would offer a tiny bit of protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and was wondering if there was any way to protect the files from being downloaded?

Nope. The browser has to download the file, hence there is nothing you can do to protect it.  You could start using a streaming solution that would make downloading the file at least more difficult, but then you'd have to use proprietary technology like Flash.

Comment: I am aware of that but by download I should have made clear that I meant intentional download by a user. Is there a way to detect this?

Comment: @Andrew yeah, I understand - the same answer still applies, though. Browsers have to download from a web URL that a user can freely access

Comment: So how does YouTube use HTML5 video tags but prevent users downloading the videos?

Comment: @Andrew I think they use a number of checks, starting with the value of the `HTTP_REFERER` header which has to match the embedding page so the video gets dispatched by the server. Then as far as I can see, they use Javascript (as you already noted) to actually fill in the value. These aren't waterproof things but I guess they can deter many users - I agree my answer isn't really correct from that point of view. Will delete soon - but I'm sure a lot of the knowledge is already present in other answers on SO. You can try searching

Comment: Funny you should mention that, see my edit above! I've been looking at all the variables in the "$_SERVER" array and noticed that when a user downloads a file directly, it doesn't pass a cache control, but I imagine that it could be bypassed. Maybe using that with the referred page check and JavaScript, I could make it increasingly difficult for people to download any files from my sites! Thanks!