# Do not show the URL in page source

Tags: html, audio, hide, http-streaming

I have some copyrighted audio files that I would like to protect from download, but show them on the website(drupal).

I have a player that works with flash and css on a link, but if you view the page source the href of the link is visible, and it is very easy to get the URL and get the files locally.

I understand that it's not possible to prevent it 100%, but what I would like to do is just to make it more difficult than seeing the url in the page source.

How can I do it?
I would like to avoid to write myself a player, because my flash knowledge is quite limited... 
I'm already hidding with Javascript the link while hoovering with the mouse of the player(which is acctually a link in terms of HTML).

I've tried an HTML obfuscator(http://htmlobfuscator.com), but it does not work properly, for one link it works, for the second and third one it doesn't...

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think is worth your time. With a normal flash grabber anyone can crawl your site for flash/audio files. The one that knows how to look at your source probably knows how to use these tools as well.

Comment: If you don't want people to be able to download your music, don't put it online. Fast, easy way :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protect audio files in HTML5 audio tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634955/protect-audio-files-in-html5-audio-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, any file which is simply embedded has to be downloaded to the user's computer in order to be played (usually it is downloaded to a temporary location then removed, but a savvy user will be able to capture the download and save it.

If you want any real protection, you'll have to use a streaming server like [Helix Streaming Server](http://www.realnetworks.com/helix/streaming-media-server/). With these, the file is not downloaded by default and the user's only real capture option is an audio cable from LineOut to LineIn. Most don't have access to this.

Comment: Thank you.Even though I agree with you, and I fully understand that 100% protection does not exist, I'm trying to reach something better than 20%. Initially since the player works with links, one could right click save as, and then they could download the file. Now I've blocked the right click via Javascript and I'm hidding the url on mouse over.

Comment: How about ajax? to get the href of the link dynamically from the database from one table where I keep the real link based on an parameter/index that I can pass to the ajax call?

Comment: Are you using PHP or similar on the backend?